# Create a hash in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

I have a beginner question:

I have an @key_table and many @values_tables.
I want to create a @table of references to hashes, so there is one table, each element points to hash with keys&values from those 2 tables presented at the beginning.

### Could anyone help me?

For example:

```
@keys = (Kate, Peter, John);
@value1 = (1, 2, 3);
@value2 = (a, b, c);
```

and I want a two-element table that point to:

```
%hash1 = (Kate=>1, Peter=>2, John=>3);
%hash2 = (Kate=>a, Peter=>b, John=>c);
```

Comment: Give us an example of the data you have and what you want the final data to look like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to create two hashes, it's really easy:

```
my ( %hash1, %hash2 );
@hash1{ @keys } = @value1;
@hash2{ @keys } = @value2;
```

This takes advantage of hash [slices](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices).

However, it's usually a mistake to make a bunch of new variables with numbers stuck on the end. If you want this information all together in one structure, you can create nested hashes with references.

Answer (score 2):

Using hash slice is most common way to populate hash with keys/values,

```
 @hash1{@keys} = @value1;
 @hash2{@keys} = @value2;
```

but it could be done in other (less efficient) way using ie. `map`,

```
my %hash1 = map { $keys[$_] => $value1[$_] } 0 .. $#keys;
my %hash2 = map { $keys[$_] => $value2[$_] } 0 .. $#keys;
```

or even `foreach`

```
$hash1{ $keys[$_] } = $value1[$_] for 0 .. $#keys;
$hash2{ $keys[$_] } = $value2[$_] for 0 .. $#keys;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump;

#Example data
my @key_table = qw/Kate Peter John/;
my @values_tables = (
   [qw/1 2 3/],
   [qw/a b c/]
);

my @table;
for my $vt(@values_tables) {
    my %temph;
    @temph{ @key_table } = @$vt;
    push @table, \%temph;
}

dd(@table);
#<--- prints:
#(
#  { John => 3, Kate => 1, Peter => 2 },
#  { John => "c", Kate => "a", Peter => "b" },
#)
```

Answer (score -1):

This will do it:

```
   use Data::Dumper;
use strict;

my @keys = ("Kate", "Peter", "John");
my @value1 = (1, 2, 3);
my @value2 = ("a", "b", "c");
my (%hash1,%hash2);


for my $i (0 .. $#keys){
    $hash1{$keys[$i]}=$value1[$i];
    $hash2{$keys[$i]}=$value2[$i];
}

print Dumper(\%hash1);

print Dumper(\%hash2);
```

This is the output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'John' => 3,
          'Kate' => 1,
          'Peter' => 2
        };
$VAR1 = {
          'John' => 'c',
          'Kate' => 'a',
          'Peter' => 'b'
        };
```

Comment: This won't even compile under `strict`: The `a, b, c` are not quoted. C-style loops? Explicit `scalar`? Really? → `for my $i (0 .. $#keys) {...}`. Well, at least you declared all your variables … (I know this comment is unneccessarily snarky, but this is simply not the kind of Perl I would want to teach)

Comment: @amon that's fine any feedback is good, it's been like 2 years since the last time I used  PERL, anyway the code runs with strict now, and it might no be very perlish or oneliner but is another approach in case you want to manipulate the values before inserting to the hash.

Comment: anyone care to explain the downvoting ? The code runs fine and does what the OP wants

Comment: Residual down-voting is probably because it uses explicit loops where slicing is a more succinct notation.